# Access each individual custom cell with Angular bootstrap calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

I'm working on an app where I need a calendar skeleton (without the standard events) so I can put tables inside each cell, so I'm using the [Angular Bootstrap Calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) with [custom cell templates](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=custom-templates). I have everything working fine in terms of displaying the custom template in each cell and being able to navigate between months, but I need to be able to access each individual day and make data available in each one.

Here's my controller:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('calendarController', function($scope, $state, moment, calendarConfig) {

    var vm = this;

    calendarConfig.templates.calendarMonthCell = 'views/calendar/dayTemplate.html';
    calendarConfig.dateFormatter = 'moment';

    vm.events = [];
    vm.calendarView = 'month';
    vm.viewDate = moment().startOf('month').toDate();

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      calendarConfig.templates.calendarMonthCell = 'mwl/calendarMonthCell.html';
    });
  });
})();
```

and the corresponding dayTemplate.html:

```
<div class="cal-month-day">

    <span
      class="pull-right"
      data-cal-date
      ng-click="calendarCtrl.dateClicked(day.date)"
      ng-bind="day.label">
    </span>
<!--
  <small style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 5px">
    There are {{ day.events.length }} events on this day
  </small> -->

  <!-- <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"> -->
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Station</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" align="top">1</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" align="top">2</td>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" align="top">3</td>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

When using the calendar as it normally is used, you can see that the days.events object has the data, but I need to access that object, or create my own so I can fill my tables. Is there a simple (or even not so simple) way to do that?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I just went back and read the [docs](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/src/services/calendarHelper.js#L123) and noticed this

> An optional expression that is evaluated on each cell generated for
>   the year and month views. calendarCell can be used in the expression
>   and is an object containing the current cell data which you can modify
>   (see the calendarHelper service [source code](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/src/services/calendarHelper.js#L123) or just console.log it to
>   see what data is available). If you add the cssClass property it will
>   be applied to the cell.

Due to my lack of knowledge, I'm not understanding how to use this to override. If I console.log calendarCell in my calendarController it chokes because that object doesn't exist. If I'm reading this correctly, I can intercept the cell data and modify, but I'm not understanding how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, RTFM turned out to be the correct answer. Per the [docs](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=cell-modifier):

```
<div ng-controller="CellModifierCtrl as vm">
  <ng-include src="'calendarControls.html'"></ng-include>
  <mwl-calendar
    events="vm.events"
    view="vm.calendarView"
    view-date="vm.viewDate"
    cell-modifier="vm.cellModifier(calendarCell)">
  </mwl-calendar>
</div>
```

goes with this in the controller:

```
vm.cellModifier = function(cell) {
  console.log(cell);
  if (cell.label % 2 === 1 && cell.inMonth) {
    cell.cssClass = 'odd-cell';
  }
  cell.label = '-' + cell.label + '-';
};
```

and voila!, you have access to the data. I'm still trying to figure out how to pass additional data into the function, but I'll open a separate question for that.

Comment: Did you figure out how to pass additional data into function because i want to access event details inside cell modifier function?