# Pass additional data to cell data function with Angular Bootstrap Calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

As detailed in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025734/access-each-individual-custom-cell-with-angular-bootstrap-calendar/38155253#38155253), I'm using Angular Bootstrap Calendar, and per the docs, have the directive config and controller set up to be able to customize the data inside each cell. Here's the controller:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('calendarController', function($scope, $state, moment, calendarConfig, $http, Formio, shiftService) {

    var vm = this;

    calendarConfig.templates.calendarMonthCell = 'views/calendar/dayTemplate.html';
    calendarConfig.dateFormatter = 'moment';

    vm.events = [];
    vm.calendarView = 'month';
    vm.viewDate = moment().startOf('month').toDate();
    var startDate = moment(this.viewDate).toISOString();
    var endDate = moment(this.viewDate).endOf('month').toISOString();

    var endpoint = 'https://abcdefghijklmno.form.io/shift/submission';
    var token = Formio.getToken();

    var shifts = shiftService.getShiftsMonth(token, startDate, endDate);

    vm.cellModifier = function(cell, shifts) {
      cell.text = 'Test Text';
      //console.log(cell);
    };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      calendarConfig.templates.calendarMonthCell = 'mwl/calendarMonthCell.html';
    });
  });
})();
```

and my service to get the data.

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('shiftService', shiftService);

  shiftService.$inject = ['$http'];
  function shiftService($http) {
    var getShiftsMonth = function (token, startDate, endDate) {
      var config = {
        headers: {
          'x-jwt-token' : token
        },
        params: {
          'date.date__gte': startDate,
          'date.date__lte': endDate 
          // limit: 10
        }
      };
      return $http.get('https://abcdefghijklno.form.io/shift/submission', config)
        .then(function(response) {
           return response.data;
        });
    };

    var addNameToShift = function(locationid) {
      return $http.get('/my/url/' + locationid);
    };

    return {
      getShiftsMonth: getShiftsMonth,
      addNameToShift: addNameToShift
    };
  }
})();
```

I get the custom data from an API endpoint, so what I want to do is get all the data for the entire month in one call and then pass it to the cell modifier function (I don't want to have to hit my API endpoint ~30 separate times when a month is viewed). However, since cellModifier gets called from the calendarHelper service, I don't see any way to pass the returned data to the cellModifier function. Do I just need to add it to $rootScope in the controller 
so it's available in the modifier, or is there a better way to get that data in there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this some more and getting [a response](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues/384#issuecomment-230106689) from Matt Lewis, it looks like the events array is the only way to get data into the cell, and from there you can add data as needed. I was able to get it to work with a little re-writing of my controller:

```
var onShifts = function(data) {
  vm.events = data;
};

var onError = function(error) {
  vm.error = 'There was an error.';
};

shiftService.getShiftsMonth(token, startDate, endDate)
  .then(onShifts, onError);

vm.cellModifier = function(cell) {
  cell.shifts = this.events;
};
```